# Does Visual Studio extension packages support asyncronous operations

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await, visual-studio-extensions

I am creating a custom visual studio extension. In its initialization code I use async-await to make async WebRequest to a remote endpoint.

The problem is that the moment I call await statement, the execution of my custom extension initialization halts and never gets back to it. I suspect VS extensions initialization code is somehow special when it comes to async programming. If anyone could point me to an explanation of why this is happening, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Show us your code.  Check for exceptions.

Comment: It isn't fundamentally different from trying to make the Main() entrypoint of a console app *async*.  The compiler can detect that mistake.  But it can't for an extension, it doesn't know beans VS extension initialization semantics.  The plumbing that is necessary to ensure an await continuation runs is simply missing.  Might change some day, not today.

Comment: @HansPassant: Actually, an `async void` extension initializer would probably work.  It wouldn't be a good idea, and it would swallow exceptions, but AFAIK, the TaskScheduler ought to still continue it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a new Package called AsyncPackage that allows async loading of your package. It has an AsyncInitialize. Taken from MSDN:

**You need to add a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.14.0.DesignTime for this to work**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.IO;

namespace asyncpackagetest
{
    [ProvideService((typeof(STextWriterService)), IsAsyncQueryable = true)]
    [ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
    [PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
    [Guid(VSPackage1.PackageGuidString)]
    public sealed class VSPackage1 : AsyncPackage
    {

        public const string PackageGuidString = "3dc186f8-2146-4d89-ac33-e216b3ead526";

        public VSPackage1()
        {

        }

        protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
        {
            this.AddService(typeof(STextWriterService), CreateService);
            await base.InitializeAsync(cancellationToken, progress);
            ITextWriterService textService = await this.GetServiceAsync(typeof(STextWriterService)) as ITextWriterService;
            await textService.WriteLineAsync(@"c:\windows\temp\async_service.txt", "this is a test");

        }

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object> CreateService(IAsyncServiceContainer container, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Type serviceType)
        {
            STextWriterService service = null;
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {
                service = new TextWriterService(this);
            });

            return service;
        }

        public class TextWriterService : STextWriterService, ITextWriterService
        {
            private Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.IAsyncServiceProvider serviceProvider;
            public TextWriterService(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.IAsyncServiceProvider provider)
            {
                serviceProvider = provider;
            }
            public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteLineAsync(string path, string line)
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path);
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(line);
                writer.Close();
            }
            public TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter()
            {
                return new TaskAwaiter();
            }
        }
        public interface STextWriterService
        {
        }
        public interface ITextWriterService
        {
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteLineAsync(string path, string line);
            TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter();
        }
    }
}
```